# What is the Julian alternative to attribute inheritance?

Tags: types, abstract-class, julia, abstract

In many programming languages, parent classes can require any subclasses to contain a specific field.

If the field is static, the same effect can be achieved in Julia in the following way.

```
julia> abstract Fruit

julia> type Apple <: Fruit end

julia> type Orange <: Fruit end

julia> type Banana <: Fruit end

julia> color(::Apple) = :red
color (generic function with 1 method)

julia> color(::Orange) = :orange
color (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> color(::Banana) = :yellow
color (generic function with 3 methods)
```

However, this will not work if the field is dynamic. In the following example, I would like to require any subtype of `Pet` to contain the field `name`.

```
julia> abstract Pet

julia> type Cat <: Pet
           name::String
           hairless::Bool
       end

julia> type Dog <: Pet
           name::String
       end

julia> abstract Bird <: Pet

julia> type Parrot <: Bird
           name::String
           color::Symbol
       end

julia> type Conure <: Bird
           name::String
       end

julia> feet(::Cat) = 4
feet (generic function with 1 method)

julia> feet(::Dog) = 4
feet (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> feet(::Bird) = 2
feet (generic function with 3 methods)
```

The types *do* have to be different, as they may have other attributes, as well, and methods may be uniquely defined for each type.

- How can I enforce this requirement? Ideally, I would not have to specify the `name` field in any of the subtypes, but if I must, so be it.
- In the case that this is impossible in Julia, what is the suggested alternative? Can I refactor this type of code to eliminate the need for this behavior entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How do I enforce it?

With tests

```
using Base.Test 
@testset "Field Contract" begin
    for sub in subtypes(Pet)
        @test fieldtype(sub, :name) == String 
        #will error if no field names string.
        #will fail if it is has wrong type
    end
end
```

### How can I have it filled in automatically on subtypes

It is technically possible to do this with metaprogramming.
I *do not* recommend it.
This is just a hack proof of concept:

```
macro declare_abstract(typename, fields...)
    quote
        abstract $(esc(typename))
        const $(esc(Symbol(:__abfields_,typename)))  = $(esc(fields))
        $(esc(typename))
    end
end

error("Please don't use this in real code") #prevent trivial copy paste

macro declare(type_expr)
    @assert type_expr.head == :type
    @assert type_expr.args[2].head == :(<:)
    parent_typename::Symbol = type_expr.args[2].args[2]
    if isdefined(Symbol(:__abfields_, parent_typename))
        @assert type_expr.args[3].head == :block
        abfields = eval(Symbol(:__abfields_, parent_typename)) #Read a globel constant. Iffy practice right here -- using eval in a macro

        push!(type_expr.args[3].args, abfields[1].args...)
    end
    type_expr
end
```

Usage example:

```
@declare_abstract Pet (name::String), (owner_id::Int)
@declare type Cat <: Pet
end
```

check it:

```
?Cat
...

Summary:
    type Cat <: Pet
Fields:
    name     :: String
    owner_id :: Int64
```

## Wait? Why do you say not to do this?

**It is a code smell.
Depending on the fields of an Abstract type should not be done.**
Julia is not well established enough to have these conventions laid out,
with standard solutions.
Here I am talking from my own experience.

*If your method takes an Abstract type as a parameter.
Then it should depend on methods of the implementing types;
but not on fields of the implementing types.
This also holds for [Informal Interfaces](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/interfaces/) too.*

It makes your code inflexible when you find that you need a subtype that does not have this field.
It's happened to me.
I think I know all the subtypes, but then I realise that I want to wrap up something by someone else as a subtype, and this field makes no sense for that. And all my code breaks

**I am not here going into a composition vs inheritance debate. Though that is related.**

#### Example

For example, 
What if you need to deal with a Pet that doesn't meet you assumptions.
Perhaps something from you wrapping a livestock package.
These pets are infact `Bees`
They don't have a name field, because they don't have names.
They have a `hive` field, but it is an `Int`.

If you were working with methods you would be fine:
Say you had a `get_identifier` method

For your types you've already prepared:
`get_identifier(x::Union{Dog,Cat})=x.name`

Then to introduce compatibility with the `Bee` type
you just add `get_identifier(x::Bee)="Member of hive# $(x.hive)"`.
And all of your code works.

On the other hand if you had `x.name` everywhere in your code, then it would all break.
Sure you can add something to the constructor, that automatically sets a name field. (And when I found myself in this situation that is what I did).
But it is a hack and a maintenance burden.
Small in this made up example of course.

#### Exception

There is an exception to this rule of course:
when you really *do* know the fields of all subtypes.
For example if I write a mathematical solver that solves a particular family of problem. and I have a type for `AbstractResults`, where each type of problem I solve has its own concrete subtype, to store special factors for this kind of result; then I know that there are only 5 possible types of problem in my family.
So I know that there are only 5 concrete subtypes of the `AbstractResults`,
and I know that they therefor all have the implementation that I have given them; and no other set of fields makes sense. (Feasible if it is all very simple types).
Then it is ok.
just don't be wrong.

#### Testing

You can check methods are implemented with some test code too

```
using Base.Test 
@testset "Method Contract" begin
    for sub in subtypes(Pet)
        @test method_exists(get_identifier, (sub,))
    end
end
```

This "enforcing contracts with tests" is a dynamic language pattern.

#### Conclusion

Depending on methods is more correct.
Methods define functionality.
Fields are simply an implementation detail.
As the definer of an abstract type, and more importantly of methods using an abstract type, you very clearly know what functionality each subtype must have.
You are less certain of the implementation.

If your method that takes as a parameter the fields on an Abstract type,
consider if it is written the right way at all